# Custom Post Type, the single-(post-type}.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I feel like I am doing something obviously simple, yet can't figure out what!
I created my custom post type = Author and then created single-Author.php to display the information of each author but when I open link of each author 404.php

here is custom post type author

```
function p2p2_register_author(){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'همکاران', 'Author' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x('همکار','Author'),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'افزودن همکار', '' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'افزودن همکاران جدید' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش همکار' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'همکار جدید' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه همکاران' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جست و جو همکار' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'همکاری یافت نشد' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'همکار در زباله دان یافت نشد' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'همکار'
    );

    register_post_type(
        'Author',
        array (
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'description'   => 'ذخیره اطلاعات مربوط به همکاران',
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'author' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
        )
    );
}
        add_action('init', 'p2p2_register_author');
        flush_rewrite_rules();
```

I also have archive-author and it works really fine but single-Author.php doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the permalink page, then flush it. I mean hit `Save Changes` button. Hope your problem is gonna fixed. If it is not then change `'has_archive' => true,` to `'has_archive' => false,` then again hit `Save Changes` button on permalinks page. Your problem will be fixed.

Comment: this is wired, some of my post type post load perfectly but some of theme not loading single-Author.php, why?!!!

Comment: It is needed to flush the permalinks after creation of every `archive-{post-type}.php` or `single-{post-type}.php` or this kinda other templates. Cause WordPress need to be recognized the new addition to the hierarchy.